# Pandas dataframe column multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

how to multiply, if you have 2 df's to multiply using selected columns , and store the result in a new column for example

df1:

```
                    AAPL IBM GOOG XOM
2011-01-10 16:00:00 1500 0   0    0
```

df2:

```
AAPL   IBM    GOOG   XOM
340.99 143.41 614.21 72.02
340.18 143.06 616.01 72.56
```

i want to multiply , aapl in df1 with 340.99 in df2 , and store the result in transaction_amount.

Comment: Could you have a look at the StackOverflow formatting guide? It's a bit hard to make out what you want right now. Also, check that your example data frames make sense.  What are the column names of df2?  That actually matters for the answer.

Comment: Hi I tried to format, and i didnt get the hang of it. The columns of df2 are different prices of the securities in df1.

Comment: See my edit to your question (once it's passed peer review.  Does df2 have an index?  pandas `DataFrames` are labeled so, by default, df1 * df2 will have a non-`NaN` in for `AAPL` only if that first row of df2 has the same index value of `2011-01-10 16:00:00` (if that's your index).

Comment: df2 , doesnot have an index. That is the problem i am facing

Comment: Presumably you know that `340.99` occurred at the timestamp `2011-01-10 16:00:00`?  Where are you getting the second dataframe and why does it not have a datetime index?

Answer (score 0):

```
transaction_amount = np.diag(df1.dot(df2.T))
```

Basically, to do what you want, you want to do some form of dot product of df1 with df2

```
df1.dot(df2)
```

but since they have matching dimensions you need to transpose one of the DataFrames

```
df2.T
```

And if you understand how matrix dot products work you'll understand you only want the array data from the diagonal of the resulting matrix. ie: You only want (AAPL price of day X * AAPL shares of day Y, where X == Y) Therefore, the values in the matrix that are relevant to you are located at (0,0), (1,1), (2,2), etc ie: the diagonal.

This line will also be useful when calculating portfolio value once you use cumsum to create a holding matrix.

Some helpful sources

http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html
http://mathinsight.org/dot_product_matrix_notation